# duplicate external static declarations not allowed in visual studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, static

I was studyng the concept of declaration and definitions (linkage, scope, duration).

But I found one unexplainable error:

The following code is fine in both gcc and visual studio 2010

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int a = 7;
extern int a;

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

But the following code generates an error in visual studio but is fine in gcc:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int a = 7;
static int a;

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", a);
}

error C2370: 'a' : redefinition; different storage class
```

Is it just a bug in visual studio compiler?

EDIT: this question turned out to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215818/why-does-redefining-a-static-global-variable-give-a-compile-time-error-when-rede).

Comment: I believe C and C++ differ on this issue - I think C specially says that two definitions of `static` variables in the same file refer to the same variable, while C++ has problems with this (I can't remember why they changed it). Make sure you're compiling as C, not C++, in Visual Studio.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does redefining a static global variable give a compile-time error when redefining a global variable does not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215818/why-does-redefining-a-static-global-variable-give-a-compile-time-error-when-rede)

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate. That question has a declaration followed by a definition, then another declaration. This one does not have that initial declaration (and while that may seem like a pure technicality, it actually makes a substantial difference to the answer).

Comment: hm... why would that "extra" declaration before a definition make substantial difference? After all, that "extra" declration would be treated as a normal declaration since the definition follows right after it.

Comment: @SHH: Well, your second snippet *is* essentially a duplicate of the first in that question. Your first and his second, however, are rather different from each other -- your's specifies `extern`, where his doesn't specify any storage class. For those, different parts of the standard are relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static int a;` by itself without an initializer is a "tentative definition", so it should be fine.  It looks like Microsoft has some kind of extension that's catching you.

Edit - it does look like a Microsoft problem.  Check out this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215818/why-does-redefining-a-static-global-variable-give-a-compile-time-error-when-rede).  The C spec itself is pretty clear that your code is fine.  From **6.9.2 External object definitions**:

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier **`static`**, constitutes a *tentative definition*. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer equal to 0.

Comment: Whoa, I need to improve my searching skills.This was a duplicate. Thanks for searching and pointing out!

Comment: @SHH - I found the dupe by searching for "tentative definition".  If you weren't looking for that exact phrase, it might have been a lot harder to find.

Comment: how does this work for automatic variables ? why does not the tentative definition apply to them ?

Comment: @parminder, no - as the spec says, tentative definitions are declarations with file scope and no initializer and no storage-class specifier (except `static`, which is ok).

Comment: The quote you've given doesn't seem entirely applicable here. According to §6.9.2/1, `static int a = 7;` clearly *is* an external definition for `a`, so (at least) the part about `...contains no external definition for that identifier..." clearly can't apply.

Comment: @Jerry, isn't this one an 'internal definition', since it's `static`?  I don't know if that nomenclature is compiler specific or not, but here's a quick reference I just found: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc03tentative_defn.htm

Comment: @CarlNorum: (§6.9.2/1): "If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and an initializer, the declaration is an external definition for the identifier." Those criteria seem to fit with the `static int a = 7;` in question.